# Is it allowed to use Admob real ads during "internal" or "closed" or "open testing" in Google Play?

Tags: android, admob

In my app I'm using **internal testing** (5 testers) and **open testing**.
[image: enabled tests]
This month I had 15 days of **Ad serving is currently limited** due to **invalid traffic concerns.**
[image: admob advise]
Now they enabled ads again without any apparently reason but the advise is still there.
I have over 3.5 millions of app openings per month and for sure I don't show and click my real ads during the development phase.
My doubt is that is not possible to show ads in the internal testing publication or the prelaunch/firebase tests.
AdMob team does not reply to my question and I don't know how to avoid this issues in the future.
**How can I do?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use production Ad units in your code then they might get clicked when running in Firebase Test Lab. Use the code below found [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab/android/android-studio#modify_instrumented_test_behavior_for_testlab) to detect if in Test Lab and prevent Ads from showing:

```
    String testLabSetting = Settings.System.getString(getContentResolver(),"firebase.test.lab");
    if ("true".equals(testLabSetting)) {
        // Do something when running in Test Lab 
        // like changing the unit id to test banner
        binding.adView.adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-12345678"
    }
```

If you want a device to show only test Ads you have to add it in Admob Settings by:

1. On the device go to Settings > Google > Ads > Your advertising ID.
2. In your Admob account go to Settings > Test Devices then add a Name, select the OS and add the Advertising ID you got in step 1.

You can request the advertising ID from your testers and add it in your AdMob Settings then remove it later when they are done testing.

Answer (score 6):

I think it is best practice to use the test ads ids throughout your development and testing phases to avoid such messages from Google.

Remember even though you do not click on the ads, they have been loaded and displayed, it's not only click on ads that generates the revenue but even the duration for which they are displayed.

Comment: so use test ads in "internal testing" or also in "open/beta testing"?

Comment: For internal testing yes(use test ads id), but for beta testing using the live ads is fine from my experience